# How to access a deeply nested DOM Nodes in Reactjs without querySelector (or any DOM API which is being discourage by Reactjs) and refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Component, which has **lots of nested DOM nodes**. I want to have **access to almost all of these nodes** for animation (which I do with **anime.js**). Also, these nodes need to interact with each other while animating and state management.

I got to know that **react discourage using querySelector and other DOM API** functions to access DOM nodes, as these components need to be independent to each other, and DOM API functions can be used to interact between different components. Also, **I don't wanna use refs for all of these nodes** in 20 to 30 js files, as this makes things confusing for me to manage.

***Is there any other simpler way to be able to access DOM nodes nested deeply in a component, and manipulate/animate its properties using anime.js?***

**Note**: I am using **styled-components** in my program. All of the jsx code below, like `<FilterOption>` are styled-component tags.

Code:

```
render() {

    const filter = [];


    //this.state.numberOfFilterOptions store the number of filter options, each will be in a Reactjs DOM Node

    for(let x = 0; x < this.state.numberOfFilterOptions; x++)
    {
        filter.push(
            <FilterOption key={x}>
                <FilterOptionSubMenu></FilterOptionSubMenu>
                <FilterOptionTitle>
                    {this.state.filterOptionsName[x]}
                </FilterOptionTitle>

                <FilterOptionTitleArrow>
                    <svg style={{width:'24px', height:'24px'}} viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill="#212121" d="... ... ..."/>
                    </svg>
                </FilterOptionTitleArrow>
            </FilterOption>
        );
    }

    return(
        <FilterPanelDIV onMouseEnter={this.onFilterPanelHoverEnter}>
            <FilterSpan>Filter</FilterSpan>

            <Filter>
                {filter}

                <FiterApplyButton>
                    <FilterApplyButtonInnerDIV/>
                    <FilterApplySpan>
                        Apply
                    </FilterApplySpan>
                </FiterApplyButton>
            </Filter>

        </FilterPanelDIV>
    );
}
```

In the code above, I want to have **access to all of the nested Nodes** of `<Filter>` in the event handling function `onFilterPanelHoverEnter()` without refs and querySelector (or any DOM API which is being discouraged by Reactjs).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ref the components, just like `FilterOption` list, just need to use `ref` to ref it. For example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.options = []
  }

  refOption(k) {
    return (opt) => this.options[k] = opt
  }

  render() {
    return Array(n).fill(0).map((k) => (
      <FilterOption key={k} ref={this.refOption(k)} />
    ))
  }
}
```

If you want to ref to `FilterOption`'s inner component or DOM node, the `FilterOption` must support it by use custom property or `React.forwardRef`. The latest version of `styled-components` supports `React.forwardRef` API, and the legacy versions supports `innerRef` property. You can see it at:

1. react forwarding refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html
2. styled-components refs: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, refs are the only React-built-in escape hatch available to you to access DOM nodes.